# JsonPatch remove command when value changed from null to undefined

Tags: typescript, antd, json-patch

Server returns data that may include optional text values. In the original object they appear as *null*. I have dynamic form (using React + Ant Design) which allows user to add more of these fields. When I save the form, the form returns the field as *undefined* if the field was never touched. Now json patch is created and it includes a remove command for the field because it changed from *null* to *undefined*.

In the future, I plan to add a changelog to record what changes have been made and due to the unwanted patch command, the changelog might include unwanted lines. How can I avoid these unwanted commands? There's no way I would start to map all data to convert all *null* to *undefined*.

Comment: Use a default value for your undefined fields